# What does "$module =>" represent when invoking the subroutine "not_in_file_ok"

Tags: perl

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Test::More tests => 6;

sub not_in_file_ok {
    my ($filename, %regex)= @_;

    open (my $fh, '<',  $filename)
            or die "couldn't open $filename for reading: $!";

    my %violated;

    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        while ( my ($desc, $regex) = each %regex ) {
            if ( $line =~ $regex ) {
                push @{$violated{$desc}||=[] }, $.;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( %violated ) {
        fail("$filename contains boilerplate test");
        diag "$_ appears on lines @{$violated{$_}}" for  keys %violated;
    }
    else {
        pass ("$filename contains no boilerplate test");
    }
}
```

now start to invoke the function above

```
sub module_boilerplate_ok  {
    my ($module ) = @_;

    not_in_file_ok ( $module =>
        'the great new $MODULENAME'    => qr/- The great new/,
        'boilerplate description'      => qr/Quick Summary of what themodule/,
        'stub function definition'     => qr/function[12]/,
    );
 }
```

My question is that the first parameter should be a "file" for the subroutine `not_in_file_ok`. Can `$module =>` represent a file? I think `$module =>` seems to be a key of a hash because it is using `=>`. who can help me understand the parameter?

Comment: Note: People frequently say that `=>` quotes the *bareword* on its LHS, but it's impossible for a bareword to appear on the LHS of `=>`. They mean that `=>` quotes the *identifier* on its LHS.

Answer (score 2):

The `=>` operator is known as the *fat comma* and is basically a comma. It has the added facility that if its left-hand parameter is a "bareword" (composed entirely of ASCII letters and digits and the underscore) then it will be implicitly quoted, for example `field1 => 99` is the same as `'field1', 99`, but that doesn't apply in this case because `$module` is not a bareword. It also implies some sort of relationship between its left and right parameters, which is why it is often used in hash initialisation to separate the key and value of a hash element

It is documented in [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator)

Your code is *identical* to this

```
not_in_file_ok ( $module,
    'the great new $MODULENAME'    => qr/- The great new/,
    'boilerplate description'      => qr/Quick Summary of what themodule/,
    'stub function definition'     => qr/function[12]/,
);
```

and in my opinion should be written that way. The `=>` doesn't have any advantages here, and it seems that the author was trying to be clever

Answer (score 0):

`=>` is the *fat comma*. It's basically another way of writing a `,`, but using it makes comma-separated-lists more obvious to the reader. Compare these:

```
%a = (
    a => 1,
    b => 2,
    c => 3,
);
%b = ("a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3,);
```

The left side of the fat comma `=>` is assumed to be text.

I'd write your sub call as

```
not_in_file_ok ( $module,
 'the great new $MODULENAME'    => qr /- The great new/,
  'boilerplate description'     => qr /Quick Summary of what themodule/,
  'stub function definition'     => qr /function[12]/,
);
```

to visually separate the `$module` argument from the remaining list.

This is working, because a Perl hash could be converted to a list (array) and back at any

```
@array1 = %hash1;
%hash2 = @array1;
```

The list/array representation of a hash is just a list of keys and values: key1, value1, key2, value2, etc. That's what you're passing as arguments to the sub.

The first line of the sub takes one argument of (into `$filename`) and creates a hash out of the remaining ones:

```
    my ($filename, %regex)= @_;
```

The second line tries to open the first argument:

```
    open (my $fh, '<',  $filename)
```

I assume it should be a filename. No matter if it's called `$module` or followed by a fat or thin/normal comma.

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator for more information.

Comment: An array is *not* a list. Please take a look at [*What is the difference between a list and an array?*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#What-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array%3F) in `perldoc perlfaq4`

Comment: No, it isn't. But here it's both: A *list* of values stored into an *array*. That's why I used both keywords.

Comment: So why don't you write that? *"list (array)"* implies that the two words are synonymous (they're not keywords).